# Creating .dll and .lib files with the VC++ command line

Tags: c, visual-c++

How can I create `.lib` files and `.dll` files in VC++ with `cl.exe` from the command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build a DLL from the command line in Windows using MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130479/how-to-build-a-dll-from-the-command-line-in-windows-using-msvc)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Visual Studio comes with a library tool called `LIB.EXE` which can be used to create library files from object files. If you set up the command line so that you have `CL.EXE` on the path, you should also be able to run `LIB.EXE`.

E.g.

```
LIB.EXE /OUT:MYLIB.LIB FILE1.OBJ FILE2.OBJ
```

To create a dll, you just use `LINK.EXE` (as for executables) but with the `/DLL` switch.

E.g.

```
LINK.EXE /DLL /OUT:MYLIB.DLL FILE3.OBJ FILE4.OBJ
```

Comment: Thanks a lot can you please also help me how i can create a dll file from the command line....

Comment: @Vineel Kumar Reddy: Updated.

Comment: Of course `LIB.EXE` breaks convention and uses `:` for specifying the outfile. No wonder people have problems with this toolset.

Comment: how do you do this for all .obj files in a directory rather than specifying individual files?

Answer (score 14):

Re making a DLL, these are shorthand form(s) if you have the source files:

```
cl /LD foo.c bar.c baz.c /FeMyImage.dll
```

or

```
cl /LD foo.c bar.c baz.c /link /out:MyImage.dll
```

are equivalent.

Comment: How to link object files using `cl`?