# How to compile C source code without a main function?

Tags: c

How can I compile my C source files without needing to put a `main` function within them?

I get an error for the `.c`files that have no main function and don't want to have to add the main function just for compilation.

Comment: For MSVC (Visual Studio, `cl`) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727187/creating-dll-and-lib-files-with-the-vc-command-line .

Answer (score 65, accepted):

On GCC, the `-c` switch is what you want.

`-c` means "compile, don't link", and you get a `name.o` output file.

Comment: I think `-c` is pretty much standard for most C compilers.

Answer (score 14):

Suppose you have hello.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
_start()
{
   exit(my_main());
}
int my_main()
{
   printf("Hello");
   return 0;
}
```

Compile as:

```
gcc  -nostartfiles  hello.c
```

and you can get an executable out of it.

Comment: Can you add citations

Answer (score 10):

Use the `-c` option of your compiler (works for GCC, option probably identical for other c compilers).

From GCC's man page:

> When you invoke GCC, it normally does
>   preprocessing, compilation, assembly
>   and linking.  The "overall options"
>   allow you to stop this process at an
>   intermediate stage.  For example, the
>   -c option says not to run the linker.  Then the output consists of object
>   files output by the assembler.

The linking phase is the step that looks for `main()` and complains if it doesn't find it.

Answer (score 4):

You can *compile* individual files without `main`, but you cannot *link* them and of course cannot *run* them since they are not complete programs. Note that valgrind is not a static analysis tool but a runtime tool, and therefore it is useless on individual translation units not linked into a runnable program.

If you want to test individual files, a common practice is to include something like the following in each file:

```
#ifdef UNIT_TEST
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* unit test code goes here */
}
#endif
```

And compile the file with `-DUNIT_TEST`.

Comment: `-D` is the command line option to predefine preprocessor macros.

Comment: Is it really common practice? I mean, more common than using cppunit or something?

Comment: I'm not sure what valgrind or testing have to do with OP's question..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compile without linking, the above answers are correct, use the `-c` switch. If you want a "freestanding" executable, then use the `-entry:function` switch. The default or "hosted environment" executable has the entry point as `-entry:mainCRTStartup` which calls `main`. Note that if you are making a `freestanding` executable, you cannot use the standard libraries beyond the `freestanding` libraries `<float.h>`, `<iso646.h>`, `<limits.h>`, `<stdalign.h>`, `<stdarg.h>`, `<stdbool.h>`, `<stddef.h>`, `<stdint.h>`, and `<stdnoreturn.h>`.

When is a `freestanding` executable written? `Kernels` and `Drivers`. If you are into hobby `os-dev`, then you need to write them. If you work for a hardware manufacturer, such as graphics card manufacturer, you will need to write drivers for them.

Some use the embedded unit tests, while others write them as separate files with conditional compilation. Remember that `#define` and `makefile` commands have some degree of overlap.

Answer (score 0):

To link with no main() in gcc, pick a function for the "entry" in place of main().
When linking, add this option:

-e entry

--entry=entry