# Unable to resolve circular dependency

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, include

Given following classes:

```
// myClass.hpp
class Child1;
class Child2;

class MyClass {
  public:
    virtual void doSomething (const MyClass&) const = 0;
    virtual void doSomething (const Child1&) const = 0;
    virtual void doSomething (const Child2&) const = 0;
};

// child1.hpp
#include "myClass.hpp"

class Child1 : public MyClass {
  public:
    virtual void doSomething (const MyClass&) const override;
    virtual void doSomething (const Child1&) const override;
    virtual void doSomething (const Child2&) const override;
};


// child2.hpp
#include "myClass.hpp"

class Child2 : public MyClass {
  public:
    virtual void doSomething (const MyClass&) const override;
    virtual void doSomething (const Child1&) const override;
    virtual void doSomething (const Child2&) const override;
};
```

The compiler gives me the errors:

```
undefined reference to 'Child1::doSomething(MyClass const&)'
```

The same error is printed for the other `doSomething(..)` functions.

I'm sure there is some mistake in including files (I use include guards for every header-file!!). My questions are: Where do I have to include the corresponding files and where do I need forward declaration?

Comment: Please check your cpp files, and if they are even compiled, add more code to allow us to see full picture of what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that there is no reference to the whole Method.

In other words you need to define the Method in a *.cpp File or directly in the header. See for example this [overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) or this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557657/linker-error-c-undefined-reference). The answers tell you that is actual not a Compiler error but a Linker error.

Edit: As Hans Olsson Answer suggests, it could also be that you need to [include your cpp files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202136/using-g-to-compile-multiple-cpp-and-h-files).

If you do not exactly know how the implementation will look like but want to know if you header-concept works you can implement them empty

```
virtual void doSomething (const MyClass&) const override {}
```

Or compiler your code with gcc with the flag "-c" which tells gcc  [enter to just do the compiling not the linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764298/compiling-c-source-code-without-a-main-function).

Comment: You're both right. Actually, it was a problem in linking instead of compiling. From now on, I'm a big fan of the "-c" compiler flag :)

Comment: But be aware that it is no "eierlegende wollmilchsau" (dont know how to translate that)

Answer (score 1):

"Undefined reference" looks like a linker problem. Ensure that you have a child1.cpp including child1.hpp and that you compile and with it; and that child1.cpp define the override function in the correct way.