# JNI problems with Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, dll, java-native-interface

Getting JNI to work under Linux is a snap, but I've been trying all day to compile it with Visual Studio, no luck. I tried the IDE, but it was really horrible/lots of hidden stuff that prevented me from doing what I wanted. I have tried "cl" on the command line, but I can't get the flags right:

cl /I (path)\include /link /LIBPATH (path)\lib /Out:name.dll -MD -LD source.cpp

This doesn't work, maybe I should use a previous version of VS?

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard in 2010.  Create a win32 console application, make sure to set the Configuration Type to a dynamic link library(dll), and you should be good to go.

Comment: Skip the multi-platform builds altogether and go with [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) :).  Alternatively use gcc or mingw to compile your code; you can avoid the hidden stuff.

Comment: You might find this question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130479/how-to-build-a-dll-from-the-command-line-in-windows-using-msvc