# how to compile and link project in command line?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, command-line

Using Visual Studio, I've written a C++ program `MyCat`, so it can compile in the VS IDE to generate a MyCat.DLL file.

Also, I can build it in command line, making use of the solution file `MyCat.sln`:

```
set VCTargetsPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\
set VisualStudioVersion = 12.0
path=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\;%path%
msbuild.exe MyCat.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /clp:Summary /nologo /fileLoggerParameters:LogFile=MyCat.Debug.log;Verbosity=normal;Encoding=UTF-8
```

However, how to do it without using the solution file (.sln) or vc project file (`MyCat.vcxproj`)?

I know there's a compiler `cl.exe` under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin`, that can compile `.h` and `.cpp` files.

But where is the linker and how to generate the target `.DLL` or `.EXE` files?

Comment: The linker is named `link` and there's also a librarian tool called `lib`. The `vc` subfolder of the installation has some batch file to set up proper environment variables for the tools.

Comment: ok but how to do it in command line, given a .sln and some .vcxproj files?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/527z7zfs.aspx

Comment: If you're worried about the command line options and/or parameters, you should know that the confgiuration parameters contain a "CommandLine" menu item, where all options/parameters are visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't add a comment so I'll add this as an answer instead.

If you had searched this site, you would have found this:
[How to build a DLL from the command line in Windows using MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130479/how-to-build-a-dll-from-the-command-line-in-windows-using-msvc)

Which works just fine.

EDIT: See the answer of Ebow Halm, and go upvote him :)