# How to use SQLite Encryption Extension (SEE) in a c# application

Tags: c#, sqlite, encryption

My application is written in c#, using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 and I'm currently using the sqlite3.dll to generate and modify the DB, and using System.Data.SQLite classes to load and save the data to the DB.

I’m now trying to add the SEE encryption to the application, I have not been able to get it right.

I followed the instructions from here:

https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/readme.wiki

got all the way to this line:

cl /Fesqlite3.exe -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC=1 shell.c see-sqlite3.c

[from developer command prompt for VS2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNYdd.png)

My problem is this builds a SQLite3.exe and I don’t know how to build it as a .dll file so I can access the methods from c#… any ideas?

With or without the SQLITE_DLL=1 line, it always build a exe not a dll….

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about just using the encrpytion in  System.data.sqlite ?

I am curious about your question as well though. My company is currently going through provisions to acquire SEE, but reading on the web I do not see much integration with c#.

I have seen that https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/ provider, incorporates the SEE.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifing the exe with parameter /Fesqlite3.exe
You need /LD as per [How to build a DLL from the command line in Windows using MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130479/how-to-build-a-dll-from-the-command-line-in-windows-using-msvc)