# C++ Compiling file to dll in runtime in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2017

I saw command for compiling in C++ GNU Compiler: `system("c++ file.cpp -o file.so -shared -fPIC");`
What is compiling file to library command in VS 2017?
After using `system("cl.exe")` or `system("MSBuild.exe")` 
I am getting error:
"'cl.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." or 
"'MSBuild.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: 1) OT: That command, most likely, starts with `g++`. 2) For Visual Studio 2017, that would be [`cl.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options?view=vs-2017).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build a DLL from the command line in Windows using MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130479/how-to-build-a-dll-from-the-command-line-in-windows-using-msvc)

Comment: The file would need to be in the path of the Environment or in the working directory. After you release your program every one of your customers would need a matching setup. Consider if you can solve your issue without a call to system at all.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for here is a command line reference.
[MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2017) is what builds for Visual Studio, that includes compiling.

To be clear MSBuild is used by Visual Studio to build Solution Files or Project files that come with all the required msbuild descriptions.

MSBuild itself imports a dependency of the compiler through target files that are installed on the system, the first of which is

```
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
```

On my system `$(VCTargetsPath)` is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets` and it too can and does `Import` more files.

Somewhere down the line the build step that ultimately uses cl.exe to compile is implemented as a `ClCompile` step.

There are different versions of `cl.exe` that depend on your build definitions and (on my installation) the paths are resolved in `Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props`.

The main difference of the `cl.exe` version is the target platform where each `cl.exe` compiler resides in its own folder. My installation has 4 versions of `cl.exe`, in folders named `x86`, `x64`, `arm`, `arm64`.

One design decision to consider - If your goal is to interpret scripts consider using a scripting language like [lua](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2017/blob/master/Presentations/Howling%20at%20the%20Moon%20-%20Lua%20for%20C%2B%2B%20Programmers/Howling%20at%20the%20Moon%20-%20Lua%20for%20C%2B%2B%20Programmers%20-%20Andreas%20Weis%20-%20CppCon%202017.pdf) where you can get ready made libraries for your c++ project out of the box.

EDIT: As a side note for [`int system( const char* command );`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) it calls something different depending on your system. you can test the system command on windows using cmd.exe. Navigate to the folder your exe compiles to and try your system calls there first. I recommand taking a crash course on cmd.exe, Working Directories and the Path environment variable in wondows.

Comment: I believe the command line compiler is `cl`.  The `MSBuild` is more like `make` utility.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yes, that is true. The wording of the question was using visual studio so i assumed that msbuild would fit the intent of the question.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I added in some of the caviats you mentioned - feel free to proof read and update.  :)