# How to define a custom build configuration type where a target that is normally a .exe is instead a DLL

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm using CMake to generate my Visual Studio solutions. Right now, CMake generates two configuration `Release` and `Debug`, under a single project. Both configs builds a win32 (.exe) application.

This works great, but I would also like to generate a third configuration, that builds a DLL instead. I'm aware that in CMake we can use `add_library(LibraryName SHARED [files])` to generate a separate a *project* that creates builds a DLL target, but that is not what I want. Instead, I would like to generate a `DLL` configuration in visual studio, along side `Debug` and `Release`.

I can get the configuration by adding `set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES Release Debug DLL)` in CMakeList, but I'm not sure how to go about actually configuring it. How do I make this custom configuration actually build a DLL? If possible, I would also like to customize the output name and directory of this configuration, just like how I'm able to with `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE` etc.

Is this possible? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: Something like `add_compile_options($<$<CONFIG:DLL>:/LD>)` [maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2220213/4074081).

Comment: AFAIK, this is impossible. Besides, it actually would be a very bad idea, a lot of things differ conceptually between dll/exe. Why would you need that ?
However, you can create an object library (or a static one) that will compile most of your files, and then add 2 more targets : 1 executable, 1 dll, each one having one specific file defining the entry point (if one).
Last: CMake usually creates 4 configurations... Did you remove RelWithDebInfo & MinSizeRelease ?

Comment: @Synxis I'm not sure we're on the same page here. I'm trying to do exactly that, have 3 targets, 2 of which builds executables, 1 builds a DLL. I have different entry points for each build target and am working on a fairly large code that already works well (we can generate both DLLs and exes manually easily). The only thing I wanted to do was to get CMake automate the configuration that we do manually.

Comment: @Synxis also, there actually isn't much difference when the project is specifically designed to export both (with the right preprocessors, etc.). Really is just selectively exporting the correct entry points and exposing certain api calls. Plenty of projects do this, why would you think it is a "very bad idea"?

Comment: No CMake project does that, since it is not what cmake configuration are for. They are used mainly to change the compiler flags, i.e., *for the same output kind*, how to build it. You want to *change the output kind*... Furthermore, even if you could pass specific flags for such a config, cmake would still consider it as the original kind (executable instead of library), and that would probably result in a lot of bugs regarding export, transitive dependencies, etc. Just follow Brecht's answer

Comment: @Synxis If that is really a limitation of CMake, then CMake is not right for our project. We can do this with ease with SharpMake at work so it is definitely a tried a tested pattern that works. We're just generating makefiles after all, it shouldn't be such a big deal. Besides, the "output kind" is but just another compiler flag.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `add_library(LibraryName SHARED [files])` you can keep the `add_library(LibraryName [files])` without `STATIC` or `SHARED` and then you can run CMake with `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF` or `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON` to build static or shared libraries respectively.

But that would require you to run CMake twice and compile twice.

To build both static and shared you can replace this in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library(LibraryName [files])
```

with:

```
add_library(LibraryName STATIC [files])
add_library(LibraryName_shared SHARED [files])
set_target_properties(LibraryName_shared PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME LibraryName)
```

You may also have to duplicate other lines (e.g. `target_link_libraries` and `install`) with the `_shared` target.

I use this method a lot to build static and shared libraries in one go for libraries whose `CMakeLists.txt` wasn't designed to do so.

As you're adding a separate target this way you should also be able to specify a separate output name and directory for it.

Comment: I mentioned in the question that add_library generate separate *projects*, which *isn't* what I want. I'm looking to generate separate *configurations*, along side the debug, release, relwithdebinfo and minsizerel configurations. I'm not sure I can see how this would achieve separate configurations

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `separate configurations`?
Is it like when you do

`cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF -S. -Bbuild_static`

 and 

`cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON -S. -Bbuild_shared`

 so that you have 2 build libraries configured differently by CMake?

Comment: Configurations. Like the Debug configuration. or the Release, RelWithDebInfo and MinSizeRel configurations. Like when you do `-DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES:STRING="Debug;Release;" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`, those configurations